# when running google maps, it occurred as follows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

[image]

when running google maps, it occurred as follows. 
-- error message --
MapAndroidTest won't run without GoolgePlay services, which are not supported by your device

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Make sure the device (or emulator) has installed Google Play Services and the same version you require in your gradle file

Comment: update playstore and repository of sdk if your using actual device then also update play app (it was automatically update when connected to internet)

Comment: Thank you, the emulator has already installed Google Play Services and sam version of gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your app on an actual device if possible, as apposed to the emulator.

Comment: Thank you, I would like to test on a emulator. is it impossible?

Comment: You could try running your emulator with a more recent API, however I believe it may be a problem with the google maps API rather than android studio. I'm not certain though, sorry.